# CSS Hide Parent Toggle Checked

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am working on a website and I finally made a responsive menu that takes up the whole screen when you click on the label. The problem is, I cannot hide it(I want to use pure css) I created a new label in the menu that tries to close the menu but it doesn't work and I am assuming that it's because a child is trying to select a parent. I am new to CSS and would really appreciate any help on how to make a close button that closes the menu(width: 0%). Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>La Regina</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pagewrap">

        <!--HEADER-->
        <header class="pagesection" id="pageheader">
            <div class="pagewidth">
                <figure id="logo">
                    <img src="img/logo-full.png" alt="Logotype La Regina">
                </figure>
                <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
                <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
                <nav>
                    <label for="toggle2">&#9776;</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="toggle2">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu</a>
                    <a href="#">About us</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!--END OF HEADER-->

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

html,
    body,
    figure {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

```
#pageheader {
    background: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.pagesection {
    padding-left: 11px;
    padding-right: 11px;
}

#logo img{
    width: 200px;;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#myNav > nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#toggle{
    z-index: 3;
}

#toggle2:checked < #myNav{
    width: 0%;
}

#toggle:checked + #myNav{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in CSS you cant go up the parent level.

But you can do this in Pure CSS.

```css
#pageheader {
    background: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.pagesection {
    padding-left: 11px;
    padding-right: 11px;
}

#logo img{
    width: 200px;;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#myNav > nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#toggle{
    z-index: 3;
}

#toggle:checked + #myNav{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>La Regina</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pagewrap">

        <!--HEADER-->
        <header class="pagesection" id="pageheader">
            <div class="pagewidth">
                <figure id="logo">
                    <img src="img/logo-full.png" alt="Logotype La Regina">
                </figure>
                <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
                <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
                <nav>
                    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu</a>
                    <a href="#">About us</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!--END OF HEADER-->

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see I've removed one of the input fields (one inside the nav) and then changed the id of the for attribute inside the nav to point to the checkbox outside the nav making use of the selector

`#toggle:checked + #myNav`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to affect is the overlay class but i do not believe you are able to do this with CSS.
You could do this with JQuery.
However, you can modify your current code so that the original toggle is still visible in the overlay and therefore when you untick that toggle, the overlay is removed.

So, in the html remove these two lines:

```
<label for="toggle2">&#9776;</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle2">
```

In your CSS change the 'top' to relative:

```
.overlay {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: relative;
right: 0;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Give that a try otherwise, I would recommend you look into JQuery and the [hide function](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)
I would also encourage checking out [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) at some point once you are comfortable with CSS since it is a great framework for mobile-first design.